# moving search box to the right side

Tags: css

I'm far from being a programmer. I'm building an online store using zencart and a template. 
OK, when I removed the language and currency boxes from my header, I noticed how some other information shifted to the centre.. like the search box. Below is part of the code, and what I want to do is to set the search box to the right side of my page, I don't know how to change, what to add/remove from the code.

```
#header-right {
    width: 500px;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

#header-promo {
    color: #d4d2d1;
    font-size: 1.65em;
    line-height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    float: right;
    margin-top: -80px;
    display: none;
}

.promo-big {
    color: #80ae18;
    font-size: 150%;
}

.promo-green {
    color: #80ae18;
}

#navMainSearch {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    top: 30px;
    right: 10px;
    z-index: 15000;
}

#navMainSearch input[type=image] {
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-left: -9px;
    margin-top: -1px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 15001;
}

.search-header-box {
    border: 2px solid #000000;
    width: 300px;
    height: 18px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    opacity: 0.6;
/*filter:alpha(opacity=60);*/;
}

.home-icon, .login-icon, .cart-icon, .checkout-icon, .logoff-icon, .account-icon {
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.h-sm {
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: It will be helpful to see the relevant HTML code, too.

Comment: @showdev: I'll try to find that now and post it

Comment: http://pastebin.com/ALHg9J2w, can you please check this code?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's difficult to execute that code because it contains PHP, template-related data, etc. We need valid code that reproduces your problem. Is it possible to build a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that demonstrates the problem? Or, as a last resort, is there a link to your live site?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the HTML, I'll take a guess and say that your header doesn't have an explicit width set. With some child elements removed, it collapsed to contain its children (including the 500px .header-right block). Your search box, floated to the right within this 500px box will appear approximately in the center of the page.

To fix it, give your header container a fixed width.

Or better yet, give me a link to your site or a jsfiddle I can play with :)